# Trying to add environment variables to zshrc but permission denied

Tags: macos, permissions, environment-variables, macos-ventura

So, I am new to mac

I trying to add environment variables to the zshrc file using

`echo "export VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE">>~/.zshrc`

But I am getting the error

`zshrc: read only file system: /.zshrc`

I checked the permissions, I have the rw permission but still no luck

Is there any other way to do it? I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere.

Please help.

using ventura 13.2.1

Comment: The problem isn't permissions, it's that `~/.zshrc` should expand to `/Users/yourname/.zshrc`, not just `/.zshrc`. What does `echo "$HOME"` print? (It should print "/Users/yourname", but from your symptom it might be blank.)

Comment: ```echo $HOME``` prints out "/Users/yourname". I had checked this. I am just not able to access it from terminal. I got the permission status using ```ls -l $HOME/.zshrc```.

Comment: Does `echo ~` print the same thing? Also, try `echo "export VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE">>$HOME/.zshrc` or if that doesn't work, `echo "export VARIABLE_NAME=VALUE">>/Users/yourusername/.zshrc`

Comment: Thanks, ```$HOME/.zshrc``` worked out. but, ```echo ~``` printed the same thing.

Comment: Then I have no idea why the original command failed. But if it's fixed now, you might as well close the question.